# ruby count based on certain combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have data in the following format

```
"stats": {
    "team": [],
    "outcome": [],
    "rank": []
}
```

I need to determine if there is a combination of 2 or more results present from the above structure then print something.

So the idea is:

```
(if stats.team.present? && if stats.outcome.present) || (if stats.outcome.present? && if stats.rank.present) || (if stats.team.present? && if stats.rank.present)
```

A better way is to create a method to add a counter that its incremented if the team, outcome, rank  has a count of greater than 0.

And then check if the counter is greater than 2.
Eg:

```
def my_count
  count = 0

  count += 1 if stats.team.count > 0
  count += 1 if stats.outcome.count > 0
  count += 1 if stats.rank.count > 0

  if count > 1
    return true
  end
end
```

Are these the only 2 options or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: FYI, there is no `++` operator in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these the only 2 options or is there a cleaner way?

A *ton* of cleaner ways, but the best ones will use [`many?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-many-3F), part of ActiveSupport.

`many?` is essentially like `any?`, but instead of asking if "one or more" meet a condition, it asks if *two or more*. It's by far the most semantically correct implementation of your question:

```
stats = { team: [], outcome: [], rank: [] }}

stats.many? { |k,v| v.present? } # false

stats = { team: [1], outcome: [1], rank: [] }}

stats.many? { |k,v| v.present? } # true
```

You can get slightly more clever with `stats.values` and `Symbol#to_proc` to shorten this further, but I don't see the need:

```
stats.values.many?(&:present?)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to transform it into an array:

```
data = {stats: { team: [], outcome: [], rank: [] }}

if data[:stats].reject{|k,v| v.empty?}.size > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
data = {"stats" => { "team" => [], "outcome" => [1], "rank" => [] }}
if data["stats"].values.count([]) > 1
    #code
end
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, is it hash or object? I will think of hash.

According to your question: some kind of MapReduce may be looking better:

```
["team", "outcome", "rank"].map{|key| stats[key].present? }.count(true) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try map/reduce and can read more [here](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/11/understanding-map-and-reduce)

after map/reduce you can check the output to see if there are any combination